# Show that the isolated points of $A$ are contained in $\partial A$ if..

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I have a feeling I'm over complicating the proof of this problem (I'm not even completely certain if its correct). Could you validate the logic or show a simpler proof?. If you choose to use a simple proof, please only use the definitions of a topology and the definitions/facts given below.

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$.

A point $s \in A$ is said to be an isolated point of $A$ if $\exists U \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $A \cap U = \{s\}$. Let $A_{is}$ denote the set of isolated points of $A$.

A point $b$ is said to be a boundary point of $A$ if for any $U \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $x \in U$, it follows that $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and $U \cap A^c \neq \emptyset$. Let $\partial A$ denote the set of all boundary points of $A$ (the boundary of $A$)

##### Fact

$\partial A = \overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$  (have not been able to use this in my proof)

##### Problem

Show that if $X_{is} = \emptyset$, then $A_{is} \subset \partial A$

##### My Proof

Since $X_{is} = \{ x \in X\ | \ \exists U \in \mathcal{T}: x\in U \land U\cap A = \{x\}\} = \{x \in X: \exists U \in \mathcal{T}: U= \{x\}\}$, the statement $X_{is} = \emptyset$ basically means that there exists no open singletons. In other words, for any $x \in X$, $\{x\} \not\in \mathcal{T}$.

Now assume that $x \in A_{is}$ but $x \not\in \partial A$. Then $\exists U_1, U_2 \in \mathcal{T}$ such that $U_1 \cap A = \{x\}$ and  $x\in U_2$ such that
$$U_2 \cap A = \emptyset$$
or
$$U_2 \cap A^c = \emptyset$$

If $U_2 \cap A = \emptyset$,then $x \not\in A$, a contradiction. If $U_2 \cap A^c$, then $U_2 \subset A$, hence $U_1 \cap U_2 = \{x\}$. But this is a contradiction as well, since $U_1 \cap U_2 \in \mathcal{T}$ and we concluded that $\mathcal{T}$ contains no singletons.

Hence the statement $(x \in A_{is}$ and $x \not\in \partial A)$ is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine, except for a detail: you forgot to write that $x\in U_2$; that's why $U_2\cap A=\emptyset$ leads to a contradiction.